# Finding and counting integer solutions to $0 \leq a^2 - b^2 -4ab \leq 2b^2 - 2a^2 -2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Do there exist integers $a,b$ satisfying the following inequality?
$$0 \leq a^2 - b^2 -4ab \leq 2b^2 - 2a^2 -2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$$

If so, how many such integers exist?

I've played around with algebra, but haven't identified a systematic way to solve $a$ and $b$ to force this inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider $a=kb$:

$0\le a^2(1-4k-k^2)\le a^2(2k^2-2-2k)\le a^2(1+k^2)$

then

$0\le a^2(1-4k-k^2)$ implies $-2-\sqrt5\le k\le-2+\sqrt5$ (I)

and

$a^2(1-4k-k^2)\le a^2(2k^2-2-2k)$ implies $k\le \frac{-1-\sqrt10}{3}$ or $\frac{-1+\sqrt10}{3}\le k$ (II)

and

$a^2(2k^2-2-2k)\le a^2(1+k^2)$ implies $-1\le k\le3$ (III)

Since the intersection of these 3 conditions is the empty set, this inequality has no answer.

Comment: @Momo yes, you are right, I did not consider this case.

Comment: $a=b=0$ seems to be a solution. The point is that you have to make sure that $a\ne 0$ before dividing by $a^2$. But other than that it looks OK. +1